# how to map a resultset field's into a class field´s

Tags: java, resultset

I looking for more "improved way" of doing this, i have this method that get´s all record´s from one id , and then "maps" then into a class, I have about 200 "tags" to map , it will a very very long chain of if´s ...example  :

```
                    Connection conn = ServerJDBCConnection.getInstance().getConnection(....);
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
                    ResultSet rs = null;
                    StringBuffer SQL = new StringBuffer("");

                    SQL.append(" select tag,value from dms_table where id =?"); 
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL.toString());
                    pstmt.setString(1, myid);
                            
                    DMSClass dmsClass = new DMSClass(myid);
                    String tag   = "";
                    
                    rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                                    tag   =rs.getString("TAG").trim();
                     
                                    if (tag.equals("Q1"))
                                            dmsClass.setQ1(rs.getString("value"));
                                    
                                    if (tag.equals("Q2"))
                                            dmsClass.setQ2(rs.getString("value"));
                                    
                                    if (tag.equals("Q3"))
                                            dmsClass.setQ3(rs.getString("value"));
                                    
                                    if (tag.equals("Q4"))
                                            dmsClass.setQ4(rs.getString("value"));
                                    .....
                    }
```

Comment: The idea of mapping query results to objects is called [object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) and in Java the standard way to do this is by using an implementation of the [Java Persistence API (JPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence), for example [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/).

Comment: @Jesper It can be an advantage to do the mapping manually and set by step in order of performance and resource usage. If that is the case you should avoid to blow up the app with JPA Antonio. If you dont care yet use JPA and do it default and "basic" without taking everything manually into account.

Comment: Hi thank you all , my problem is that a I´m working on a very old legacy system .. I will look at " object-relational mapping "  technique .. I can´t use hibernate or jpa for this

Comment: the other thing is that all class the field´s ( just one id / one class ) are a set of +/- 200  record´s in the database ... witch database record contain´s only one class field , the class as about 200 field´s

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection then, where you can create a map at application runtime and throughout your application lifecycle ypu can use that for setting fields values like this -

```
public class Main {
static final Map<String, Field> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (Field field : DMSClass.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        fieldMap.put(field.getName(), field);
    }
}

public static void getFromDB(){
    ..........
    .........
    while (rs.next()) {
        tag   =rs.getString("TAG").trim();
        fieldMap.get(tag).set(dmsClass, rs.getString("value"));
    }
}
}
```